# Why did SpaceX change Falcon 9’s engine configuration?

Tags: falcon-9, design

Why did the Falcon 9 go from a 3x3 configuration to a ring of 8 around a central engine? Was there some sort of aerodynamical advantage to be found or something?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9_v1.1

[image: wikipedia image]

Comment: I thought I remembered reading about some improvement for single and double engine-out events, remaining thrust would be closer to the center, but I can't find anything about that nor argue it geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

the main reason is simplicity. in a grid, you have 4 way symmetry. with the ring, you have 8 way symmetry. this makes it so all your engine mounting parts are the same, while before your corners and edges needed different parts.

Comment: Do you have any evidence stating that is why SpaceX made the change?

Comment: https://blogs.nasa.gov/spacex/2014/04/18/meet-the-octaweb/ says reduces weight and streamlines manufacturing

Comment: Consider editing that in to your answer.